# Rails jQuery AJAX from within JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a .slim file I have:

```
javascript:
  AUTH_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.inspect};
  $(document).ajaxSend(
    function(event, request, settings) {
      settings.data = settings.data || "";
      settings.data += (settings.data ? "&" : "") 
                       + "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent(AUTH_TOKEN);
    });
  $.get("/say/goodbye", function(data) { alert('get success'); });
```

In my say controller I have:

```
def goodbye
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

AJAX call $.get does nothing.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

(Note, I've written everything here in one file for simplicity so I can experiment)

Comment: have you created a goodbye.js.erb so the response could be generated? [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) may help

Comment: The filter is `javascript:` with a lower-case J, give that a shot.

Comment: @stonean you're right, but that was only a typo in my question .. in the code I had it lower case.  Have corrected my question. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The problem is HTML encoding of AUTH_TOKEN.  Adding html_safe makes it work.  So we get:

```
AUTH_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.inspect.html_safe};
```

Not sure if there is a better way, but this works now and AJAX call is executed.